# Custom Search JSON API & AMP – show search result without refresh?

Tags: ajax, amp-html, google-custom-search

I use Google Custom Search on my website (JSON API, not generated script tag from Google). On search form submit I send ajax request to https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?q=QUERY&cx=MY_ENGINE&key=MY_API_KEY

The result is JSON object with all those informations about search results. As it is async, I don't have to refresh page. I just fill

```
<div id="searchResult></div>
```

with data I have received.

But how can I handle JSON response on amp page (without refreshing)?

Comment: Provide more information so people can understand what problem you have.

Answer (score 1):

Use `amp-list` component in combination with `amp-mustache`

Comment: `@Stefany Newman` is correct  - see the amp.dev search function for a template